# Bind value between control in different view -- WPF / MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

in my MVVM application (in wpf)
i have two view and I want to bind the context of my label on my textbox value (in the other view)

SelectorView.xaml contain this control:
`<TextBox  x:Name="tbArt" value="XX"/>`

DescriptionView.xaml contain this control:
`<label context="{binding on the tbArt value????}">`

Is that possible directly without going in code behing and viewmodels ?
Will the label be refresh automatically ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are these views separate `Pages` or are they controls hosted in the same page?

Comment: they are control  in a same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of the controls databinds to the same property the label will refresh when the value is changed.Make sure that the property triggers property changed when it gets changed.

ex:
in XAML.

```
 <TextBox x:Name="tbArt" value="{Binding Path=TheProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<label context="{binding TheProperty}">
```

in the textbox make sure you use:

> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

. otherwise the property won't be changed until focus is shifted from the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is display the value of one control in another control within the same window/page, you could do the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbArt" Text="XX" />
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Text", ElementName=tbArt}" />
```

This will bind the content of the Text of the label to a control with the name "tbArt".  You can do the same thing with other properties of the control as well.

For instance,

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbArt" Text="XX" Width=33 />
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=tbArt}" />
```

will display "XX" in the textbox and "33" in the label.